# BETWEEN operator not comparing dates correctly in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I've got a simple query:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM TABLE
 WHERE EventDateTime BETWEEN '2016-05-12 00:00:00' and '2016-05-12 23:59:59'
```

For some reason, the query output includes rows with a datetime of 2016-05-13 00:00:00.

Using CAST to convert the string to datetime removes the values for 2015-05-13:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM TABLE
 WHERE EventDateTime BETWEEN CAST('2016-05-12 00:00:00' AS DateTime) and CAST('2016-05-12 23:59:59' AS DateTime)
```

What would cause this?

Comment: is your datatype a smalldatetime? The doc says values of 23:59:59 will round up. Maybe use >= and < rather than between? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182418.aspx

Comment: @Jeremy Good call! I think that's what was causing it

Comment: BTW: you should change your datetime literals to `'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss'` (i.e. `'2016-05-12T00:00:00'` and `'2016-05-12T23:59:59'`). See here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d0f28d86-fea1-40f6-b982-65f6849b9eca/how-to-code-datetimeliteral-in-sql-server?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE EventDateTime >= '2016-05-12 00:00:00' 
  AND EventDateTime < '2016-05-13 00:00:00'
```

The `BETWEEN` operator is notoriously "tricky" to get right...

Answer (score 0):

You can prefer below query. Instead of cast To and From Date, you can cast EventDateTime in Date.this will return accurate

```
 SELECT *
 FROM TABLE
 WHERE CAST(EventDateTime as DATE) ='2016-05-12'
```

Comment: That works in SQL Server 2008 and above, but the Date type doesn't exist in SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 0):

**For  SQL Server 2005 you can use below code :**

```
SELECT *
 FROM TABLE
 WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),EventDateTime,111) ='2016/05/12'
```